# Get hasMany relationship through 4 levels of users childs

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-9

I have a users table that contains:

```
id
parent_id   //=> refers to the users table
role        // admin, salesman, agent, agent_account
```

and cards table :

```
id
user_id     //refers to a user with "agent_account" role
```

- user with `admin` role has many childs of users with `salesman` role
- user with `salesman` role has many childs of users with `agent` role
- user with `agent` role has many childs of users with `agent_account` role
- user with `agent_account` role has many `cards`

I want to define the relationship of policies in the user form so that the user can access all of their child policies

```
public function cards()
    {
        switch ($this->role) {
            case 'admin':
                # return all cards
                break;
            case 'agent':
                # foreach $this->child as $ch
                # $allCards += $ch->cards;
                #return $allCards;
                break;
            case 'agent_account':
                return $this->hasMany(Card::class, 'user_id');
                break;
            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }
}
```

How do I return a variable of relationship type and how do I bring the relationships together :how i can do this =>(`$allCards += $ch->cards;`)?

Is there a better way or mechanism to solve this problem?

Comment: Im not sure i understand your question, but, at the database level, the relationship is such that a user has many policies. Restricting the result based on the user role is a business rule and therefore better handled elsewhere, like model policies (not to be confused with the policies you referenced in the question). https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/authorization#creating-policies

Comment: No, not that kind of policy let's say cards or files instead @user3532758